# how to upload files in mapped drive using asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Need to upload files in mapped drive. i tried with UNC path. locally i tried with 2 systems its working fine. but in production environment its not working. Scenario is, 2 systems with windows 2003 server. one is app server and second is data server. Hosted app in IIS. Its something with the drive/folder permissions. help needed. Tks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the app is run by a user that is allowed to go to that drive (not anonymous) and has read write permissions. Make sure the user you created on both machines have same password and username.

Comment: "same password and username" - or alternatively, that the accounts are centralised via AD etc